# Invalid file descriptor while pushing to remote

Tags: git, proxy, gitlab, rstudio-server

I have a git repo on RStudio Server and its remote on the internal Gitlab of my company. When I push to the remote for the first time in the session, I'm usually asked for my password as my username is saved. But this time I face this error when trying to push, fetch or pull from the remote:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://internalgitlab.mycompany.com/myusername/reponame/': Invalid file descriptor
```

I tried

```
git push https://user:pwd@internalgitlab.mycompany.com/myusername/reponame.git
```

but I get the same error.

I checked `http.proxy` and `https.proxy`, it's well configured. I also tried to pull the remote repo on my computer and it works. So the problem must be on the Rstudio Server.

Here is the result of `strace git push` (I just kept the master branch):

```
execve("/usr/local/bin/git", ["git", "push"], [/* 121 vars */]) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x163b000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7f0a2ee000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/R/3.6.2/lib64/R/lib/tls/x86_64/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/opt/R/3.6.2/lib64/R/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffed7c369c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/R/3.6.2/lib64/R/lib/tls/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/opt/R/3.6.2/lib64/R/lib/tls", 0x7ffed7c369c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/R/3.6.2/lib64/R/lib/x86_64/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/opt/R/3.6.2/lib64/R/lib/x86_64", 0x7ffed7c369c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/R/3.6.2/lib64/R/lib/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/opt/R/3.6.2/lib64/R/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=61, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib64/tls/x86_64/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffed7c369c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/tls/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/tls", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=6, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib64/x86_64/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/x86_64", 0x7ffed7c369c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0p!\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=90664, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2183688, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7f09eb8000
mprotect(0x7f7f09ecd000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7f0a0cc000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x14000) = 0x7f7f0a0cc000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/opt/R/3.6.2/lib64/R/lib/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/tls/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\"\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=44448, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7f0a2ed000
mmap(NULL, 2128952, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7f09cb0000
mprotect(0x7f7f09cb7000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7f09eb6000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f7f09eb6000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/opt/R/3.6.2/lib64/R/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/tls/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0m\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=144792, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2208904, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7f09a94000
mprotect(0x7f7f09aab000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7f09caa000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16000) = 0x7f7f09caa000
mmap(0x7f7f09cac000, 13448, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7f09cac000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/opt/R/3.6.2/lib64/R/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/tls/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\20\35\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2127336, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3940800, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7f096d1000
mprotect(0x7f7f09889000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7f09a89000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b8000) = 0x7f7f09a89000
mmap(0x7f7f09a8f000, 16832, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7f09a8f000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7f0a2ec000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7f0a2ea000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f7f0a2ea740) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7f09a89000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7f09caa000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7f09eb6000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7f0a0cc000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f6000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f7f0a2ef000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f7f0a2eaa10)         = 11780
set_robust_list(0x7f7f0a2eaa20, 24)     = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x7f7f09a9a7e0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f7f09aa35e0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x7f7f09a9a870, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f7f09aa35e0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
open("/dev/null", O_RDWR)               = 3
close(3)                                = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x163b000
brk(0x165c000)                          = 0x165c000
brk(NULL)                               = 0x165c000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=106070960, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 106070960, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7f031a8000
close(3)                                = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [PIPE], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_DFL, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f7f09706270}, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, 8) = 0
getcwd("/home/bureau.si.interne/touronaug/projets/PV_ML", 129) = 48
stat("/home/bureau.si.interne/touronaug/projets/PV_ML", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=35, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/bureau.si.interne/touronaug/projets/PV_ML/.git", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=15, ...}) = 0
lstat("/home/bureau.si.interne/touronaug/projets/PV_ML/.git/HEAD", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=31, ...}) = 0
open("/home/bureau.si.interne/touronaug/projets/PV_ML/.git/HEAD", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "ref: refs/heads/nouveaux_parcs\n", 255) = 31
read(3, "", 224)                        = 0
close(3)                                = 0
lstat("/home/bureau.si.interne/touronaug/projets/PV_ML/.git/commondir", 0x7ffed7c37d50) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/bureau.si.interne/touronaug/projets/PV_ML/.git/objects", X_OK) = 0
access("/home/bureau.si.interne/touronaug/projets/PV_ML/.git/refs", X_OK) = 0
lstat(".git/commondir", 0x7ffed7c37e00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open(".git/config", O_RDONLY)           = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=837, ...}) = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=837, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7f0a2e8000
read(3, "[core]\n\trepositoryformatversion "..., 8192) = 837
read(3, "", 8192)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f7f0a2e8000, 8192)            = 0
getcwd("/home/bureau.si.interne/touronaug/projets/PV_ML", 129) = 48
stat(".git", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=15, ...}) = 0
lstat(".git/commondir", 0x7ffed7c37e50) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/local/etc/gitconfig", R_OK) = 0
open("/usr/local/etc/gitconfig", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=44, ...}) = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=44, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7f0a2e9000
read(3, "[credential]\n\thelper = cache --t"..., 4096) = 44
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f7f0a2e9000, 4096)            = 0
access("/home/bureau.si.interne/touronaug/.config/git/config", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/bureau.si.interne/touronaug/.gitconfig", R_OK) = 0
open("/home/bureau.si.interne/touronaug/.gitconfig", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=315, ...}) = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=315, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7f0a2e8000
read(3, "# Ceci est le fichier de configu"..., 8192) = 315
read(3, "", 8192)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f7f0a2e8000, 8192)            = 0
access(".git/config", R_OK)             = 0
open(".git/config", O_RDONLY)           = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=837, ...}) = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=837, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7f0a2e8000
read(3, "[core]\n\trepositoryformatversion "..., 8192) = 837
read(3, "", 8192)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f7f0a2e8000, 8192)            = 0
access("/usr/local/etc/gitconfig", R_OK) = 0
open("/usr/local/etc/gitconfig", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=44, ...}) = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=44, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7f0a2e9000
read(3, "[credential]\n\thelper = cache --t"..., 4096) = 44
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f7f0a2e9000, 4096)            = 0
access("/home/bureau.si.interne/touronaug/.config/git/config", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/bureau.si.interne/touronaug/.gitconfig", R_OK) = 0
open("/home/bureau.si.interne/touronaug/.gitconfig", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=315, ...}) = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=315, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7f0a2e8000
read(3, "# Ceci est le fichier de configu"..., 8192) = 315
read(3, "", 8192)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f7f0a2e8000, 8192)            = 0
access(".git/config", R_OK)             = 0
open(".git/config", O_RDONLY)           = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=837, ...}) = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=837, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7f0a2e8000
read(3, "[core]\n\trepositoryformatversion "..., 8192) = 837
read(3, "", 8192)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f7f0a2e8000, 8192)            = 0
lstat(".git/commondir", 0x7ffed7c37670) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat(".git/HEAD", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=31, ...}) = 0
open(".git/HEAD", O_RDONLY)             = 3
read(3, "ref: refs/heads/master\n", 256) = 31
read(3, "", 225)                        = 0
close(3)                                = 0
lstat(".git/refs/heads/master", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=41, ...}) = 0
open(".git/refs/heads/master", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "53bf6ecc5c0b10e2fefc7db73c13da40"..., 256) = 41
read(3, "", 215)                        = 0
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(2, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(2, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
pipe([3, 4])                            = 0
pipe([5, 6])                            = 0
pipe([7, 8])                            = 0
stat("/usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-remote-https", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=6648080, ...}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [], 8) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f7f0a2eaa10) = 11781
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
close(8)                                = 0
read(7, "", 8)                          = 0
close(7)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
close(6)                                = 0
dup(5)                                  = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0 (flags O_RDONLY)
write(4, "capabilities\n", 13)          = 13
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7f0a2e9000
read(3, "fetch\noption\npush\ncheck-connecti"..., 4096) = 38
write(4, "option progress true\n", 21)  = 21
read(3, "ok\n", 4096)                   = 3
write(4, "option verbosity 1\n", 19)    = 19
read(3, "ok\n", 4096)                   = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".git/refs/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
getdents(6, /* 5 entries */, 32768)     = 136
stat(".git/refs/heads", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=10, ...}) = 0
stat(".git/refs/tags", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=3, ...}) = 0
stat(".git/refs/remotes", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=3, ...}) = 0
getdents(6, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(6)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".git/refs/heads/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
getdents(6, /* 10 entries */, 32768)    = 336
stat(".git/refs/heads/master", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=41, ...}) = 0
lstat(".git/refs/heads/master", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=41, ...}) = 0
open(".git/refs/heads/master", O_RDONLY) = 7
read(7, "e4de58fc461103f2e70a8138093034d2"..., 256) = 41
read(7, "", 215)                        = 0
close(7)                                = 0
getdents(6, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(6)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".git/refs/remotes/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
getdents(6, /* 3 entries */, 32768)     = 80
stat(".git/refs/remotes/origin", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=11, ...}) = 0
getdents(6, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(6)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".git/refs/remotes/origin/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
getdents(6, /* 11 entries */, 32768)    = 368                             = 0                               = 0
stat(".git/refs/remotes/origin/master", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=41, ...}) = 0
lstat(".git/refs/remotes/origin/master", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=41, ...}) = 0
open(".git/refs/remotes/origin/master", O_RDONLY) = 7
read(7, "e4de58fc461103f2e70a8138093034d2"..., 256) = 41
read(7, "", 215)                        = 0
close(7)                                = 0
getdents(6, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(6)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".git/refs/tags/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
getdents(6, /* 3 entries */, 32768)     = 88
stat(".git/refs/tags/experiment_v1", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=41, ...}) = 0
lstat(".git/refs/tags/experiment_v1", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=41, ...}) = 0
open(".git/refs/tags/experiment_v1", O_RDONLY) = 7
read(7, "4246586d9475dfde5c867b9cc71389b3"..., 256) = 41
read(7, "", 215)                        = 0
close(7)                                = 0
getdents(6, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(6)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".git/refs/bisect/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open(".git/packed-refs", O_RDONLY)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".git/objects/pack", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
getdents(6, /* 4 entries */, 32768)     = 192
access(".git/objects/pack/pack-88bdca67b6f24d507d17e0d6df2d6ea1ed500acf.keep", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat(".git/objects/pack/pack-88bdca67b6f24d507d17e0d6df2d6ea1ed500acf.pack", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=24653277, ...}) = 0
getdents(6, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(6)                                = 0
open(".git/objects/info/alternates", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open(".git/objects/pack/pack-88bdca67b6f24d507d17e0d6df2d6ea1ed500acf.idx", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=44192, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 44192, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 6, 0) = 0x7f7f0a2de000
close(6)                                = 0
lstat(".git/objects/3d/a58b5e560e01266891c07ad66e174ddd59d813", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=195, ...}) = 0
lstat(".git/objects/e4/de58fc461103f2e70a8138093034d2898cf202", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=284, ...}) = 0
lstat(".git/objects/53/bf6ecc5c0b10e2fefc7db73c13da40b643983c", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=193, ...}) = 0
lstat(".git/objects/b0/c9ed1055d0d964483d5af5cf980b7740bcd3c8", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=185, ...}) = 0
lstat(".git/objects/9c/7e71d7cb4d055b2be5291c0bef2fee440ee527", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=194, ...}) = 0
lstat(".git/objects/8a/f5c2f9d2f66339f7947819cc1e12dd70de2b2e", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=193, ...}) = 0
lstat(".git/objects/51/2a79ad718bdee0f23e2cdc738f9ebb5c906856", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=193, ...}) = 0
lstat(".git/objects/f2/0245b91dace2f02244dbc7014d0274e11263f6", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=199, ...}) = 0
lstat(".git/objects/3d/a58b5e560e01266891c07ad66e174ddd59d813", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=195, ...}) = 0
lstat(".git/objects/e4/de58fc461103f2e70a8138093034d2898cf202", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=284, ...}) = 0
lstat(".git/objects/e9/21629a346e116ae6a3850add66f4b56b63e462", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=202, ...}) = 0
lstat(".git/objects/ea/6804702efdf4ad869f582ad388830492711411", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=186, ...}) = 0
lstat(".git/objects/2a/275b3ff46d64cbb0f20a8b029a662f8a621997", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=279, ...}) = 0
lstat(".git/objects/9c/7e71d7cb4d055b2be5291c0bef2fee440ee527", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=194, ...}) = 0
lstat(".git/objects/8a/f5c2f9d2f66339f7947819cc1e12dd70de2b2e", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=193, ...}) = 0
lstat(".git/objects/51/2a79ad718bdee0f23e2cdc738f9ebb5c906856", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=193, ...}) = 0
lstat(".git/objects/f2/0245b91dace2f02244dbc7014d0274e11263f6", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=199, ...}) = 0
lstat(".git/objects/42/46586d9475dfde5c867b9cc71389b3fefc2de0", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=169, ...}) = 0
dup(5)                                  = 6
fcntl(6, F_GETFL)                       = 0 (flags O_RDONLY)
close(6)                                = 0
write(4, "list for-push\n", 14)         = 14
read(3, fatal: unable to access 'https://internalgitlab.mycompany.com/myusername/reponame/': Invalid file descriptor
"", 4096)                       = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=11781, si_uid=1390460283, si_status=128, si_utime=2, si_stime=7} ---
exit_group(128)                         = ?
+++ exited with 128 +++
```

---

EDIT

Setting the NO_PROXY environment variable seems to solve the problem. However I don't understand why, as I didn't need this before.

Comment: "Invalid file descriptor" is an odd error to get and usually indicates a bug in the software (in this case, in Git itself). If you can run this with system call tracing, that might help pin down where the bug is.

Comment: @torek I added the output of strace.

Comment: Odd, there's no EBADF error. (Did you use the inherit option?) Based on the NO_PROXY thing it looks like something has gone wrong with the libcurl proxy code.